# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

The error lines have comments on them. I don't know how to fix it help! I tried changing the spot where it spawns but that didn't work.

```
if(z[image].getColorAt(x,y).equals(Color.white))
```

and

```
addObject(new Char(0,0),80,360);
```

Details:

```
public Char(int up,int wep){
    setImage(buffer);
    upgrade=up;
    weapon=wep;
    for(image=0;image<20;image++){
        for(int x=0;x<28;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<24;y++){
                if(z[image].getColorAt(x,y).equals(Color.white)) // this is part of the error)
                    z[image].setColorAt(x,y,alpha);
                }
            }
        }   
    }



addObject(new control(1),300,200);
setPaintOrder(control.class , door.class,overlay.class,projectile.class,elevator.class,sword.class,upgrade.class,bat.class,fall.class,Tank.class,Enemy.class,bullet.class,platform.class,Char.class,lever.class);
setActOrder(elevator.class,Char.class);
addObject(new Char(0,0),80,360); // this line is part of the error
setBackground("Back1.png");
map = new GreenfootImage("map1.png");
addObject(new overlay(),300,200);
```

Comment: How is z defined? (Also can you post the whole exception)

Comment: Bet it's all about z having less than 20 elements, more exactly 10. So, at 11 it dies because no such index is found.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how array "z" created, but it looks it has only 11 elements, so the last element is z[10], and accesing to z[11], the non-existing 12. element, causes IndexOutOfBoundsException.

You may use "z.lenght" instead of "20" in for loop

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For clarifications to the question, please consider using comments in the question itself.

Comment: @carlosfigueira comments to other peoples questions are only [allowed for users with 50 points, minimum](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment)